# Is there anyway to start Apache Zeppelin faster?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

When I start Apache Zepplin, it takes about 10 minutes until it is up and ready to use.  Is there anyway to shorten this time?

Comment: Hi, whats your zeppelin version and JDK version?

Comment: I guess you are using JDK 8 with Zeppelin built by JDK 7. I faced the same issue before. It shouldn't be. Could you try with JDK 8?

Comment: I am running JDK 8

Comment: I there is a typo. Could you try it with JDK7?

Comment: With JDK7 is even slower

Comment: Actually, iI don't know what version of zeppelin you are using, but hope this command would be helpful. This runs 0.7.2 bin in a container. `docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm -v $PWD/logs:/logs -v$PWD/notebook:/notebook -e ZEPPELIN_LOG_DIR='/logs' -e ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_DIR='/notebook' --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.7.2`